# TextOverflow breaks at underscore

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
Flexible(
                        
                          child: Text('@lon_ggggggggggggggggggggText',
                          softWrap: false,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30.0,fontFamily: 'ProfileHeading'),maxLines: 1,)),
```

output expected lon_ggggggggg.... 
output lon...

[image: output]

How can this be resolved ?
edit: Flexible is used because using the Text widget inside Row

Comment: this is happening because  soft wrap, is wrapping by word and not by symbol, and the underscore symbol is dividing words

Answer (score 0):

Use **`AutoSizeText`** widget and use overflow property if needed:-

```
  Expanded(
          child:AutoSizeText("@lon_ggggggggggggggggggggText",
                              maxLines: 1,minFontSize:10,textAlign:TextAlign.center)),
```

For more info try out this [auto_aize_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)